# rm with invert-match

Tags: awk, sed, grep, rm

I submitted 6490 jobs to our HPC

```
> ls -1 split-data/*.fasta | wc -l
6490

> ls -1 split-data/*.fasta
split-data/utg000001l.fasta
split-data/utg000002l.fasta
split-data/utg000003l.fasta
split-data/utg000004l.fasta
split-data/utg000005l.fasta
```

Unfortunately, 93 jobs were put on hold.

```
> qjobs | grep racon
       5240703 racon-3/utg001564l-racon-3.fasta  H   1     1   0     10.0   0.0    150   :03   
       5241418 racon-3/utg002276l-racon-3.fasta  H   1     1   0     10.0   0.0    150   :02   
       5241902 racon-3/utg002759l-racon-3.fasta  H   1     1   0     10.0   0.0    150   :03   
       ...
```

Now, I would like to resubmit the 93 held jobs again and in order to do it, I would like to delete input files which `racon` successfully completed.

The below commands find files which I do not want to delete.

```
 qjobs | grep "racon" | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed 's|racon-3/||' | sed 's|-racon-3||' 
utg001564l.fasta
utg002276l.fasta
utg002759l.fasta
utg002919l.fasta
utg003133l.fasta
...
```

How is it possible to combine the above commands with `rm` in order to achieve an invert-match deletion?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can't you make the file deletion part of the job you have submitted? Depending on whether you fasta files are input or output, delete the current fasta file before starting (output), or delete the file after finishing (input).  Parsing the output of `qjobs` seems a bit unreliable.

Comment: Invert the grep with a `-v`

Comment: @RakeshSharma You would get all the lines in the `qjobs` output that doesn't match the pattern.  I'm assuming they want to delete all files that doesn't match the filenames that they extract. This is not the same thing.

Comment: KIndly post expected output

Comment: @kusalananda you maybe right, but the question is so ambiguously worded, that I took whatever I could understand. That's what happens when clarity in posting is not adhered to. We really ought to have compulsory fields in the question that specify some minimum data, like as: a) input, b) expected output, c) cat -e <input.file> so that CRLF issues are sorted right away, d) OS and tool versions used, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and updated the question.

Comment: Have you solved this problem ? If not let us know, so a satisfactory solution may be provided to you.  In that case, lease also say whether files to be retained are all characterized by some specific string or `qjobs`'s output pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 split-data/*.fasta | cut -d/ -f2 |sort > /tmp/total
qjobs | grep "racon" | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed 's|racon-3/||' | sed 's|-racon-3||' | sort >  /tmp/dnot
comm -23 /tmp/total /tmp/dnot |
xargs printf 'split-data/%s\n' |
xargs -l -t rm
```